# Replacing contact form with chatbot

Tags: forms, user-research, chatbots

I'm redesigning the user experience in a portal for a IT company. I'd like to know if anyone has done a study on pro & cons to replace the contact form page with a chatbot, or more general if anyone has experience in.

Answer (score 1):

There is already something like that for you, made by [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/).

From the page:

> Amazon Lex is a service for building conversational interfaces into
>   any application using voice and text. Lex provides the advanced deep
>   learning functionalities of automatic speech recognition (ASR) for
>   converting speech to text, and natural language understanding (NLU) to
>   recognize the intent of the text, to enable you to build applications
>   with highly engaging user experiences and lifelike conversational
>   interactions.

So, there is already an API to put that into your app and have a bot talking to you.

Amazon claims to already have several customers using the bot on their pages, including OhioHealth, CapitalOne, HubSpot and NASA.

Comment: Interesting, but this doesn't answer the question of pros and cons from a user experience point of view.

Answer (score 0):

**Chatbots are a good thing if implemented right, in my point of view**

I view chatbots as search-centric information interfaces. For help and other kinds of documents, it is definitely a plus. Of course the quality of the docs and provided functions are the real challenge.

The chatbots I talked to so far are the dumbest search engines I saw. This has not bothered me at all. After a few questions I learned that it is more efficient to send just the keywords of what I was looking for.

I think the challenge is to write the info in a way that the bot will be able to index right. If there are too many documents and unclear language, people will see many results for their inquiry and get annoyed.

Keep stats on inquires that does not satisfy the user, such as results presented but not clicked or explicitly set by the users as unhelpful. Establish a process to review those stats and update the docs seen by the bot or its programming.